# Error Message: The coordinates or measures are out of bounds

Tags: arcscene, tin, extrude

When extruding between 2 TINs using a polygon feature class, above error is received.

The coordinate system for each layer is consistent, the shapefile has no Z or M values, and I have recalculated XY extent.

But the error is still being returned. Is there anything I could be missing?

Comment: Please [Edit] the question to specify the exact false origin and precision values, particularly in the Z dimension, and the range of values in your TINs.